# Restrict all ip address but allow only for web host ip | .NET

Tags: .net, hosting, ip-address

I have my frontend app in one hosting and backend app in other hosting

I want that my app restrict all ip address and allow only ip from frontend app hosting

In my app .net 6 I use white list for IP Address by this flow https://www.infoworld.com/article/3663443/how-to-implement-ip-whitelists-in-aspnet-core-6.html

But as I see .net app get my client IP, from my home internet. Not from ip hosting of frontend app and the flow example works good but not with hosting ip app.

How I can get only hosting ip and allow only it?

Comment: What is the app and the app hosting?

Comment: Angular 16. Sorry, can't to say the name. Only what I can to say that hosting redirect client id to backend service, not hosting ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

The request is done by the app running on the client, then server see only the client IP.

Maybe you can retrieve host information from the request's header, but don't use it at security purpose (because this can be easily manipulated).

---

If you open a other question to specify your use case, maybe we can suggest a alternative.